# Correct usage of TPL to launch a cancellable ASync operation

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, task-parallel-library

I have been using the TPL to run database fetches in a non-UI thread, allowing the UI to carry on whilst they take place. The code in the example below is called to populate a detail pane in a master detail view. There's a tree view in the master pane and different data is fetched based on the node clicked. The UI lets the user cancel a fetch, and automatically cancels a fetch should they select a different node while a fetch is active. This is the code I'm using to do this:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub FetchSummary()
  If DBKey.PresentAndSet(DataKey) Then
    _view.BeginDataFetch()
    ' Cancel any active refresh
    If TaskCancelTokenSource IsNot Nothing Then TaskCancelTokenSource.Cancel()
    TaskCancelTokenSource = New CancellationTokenSource
    Dim ctok = TaskCancelTokenSource.Token
    Dim dataTask = New Task(Of IEnumerable(Of IAssignSailingPart.ISummary))(Function() FetchsummaryData(Context, DataKey), ctok)
    Dim uiSyncContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext
    dataTask.ContinueWith(Sub(dt) _view.Data = dt.Result, ctok, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, uiSyncContext)
    dataTask.ContinueWith(Sub(dt) _view.FailDataFetch("There was an error fetching the data, try refreshing"), Nothing, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, uiSyncContext)
    dataTask.ContinueWith(Sub(dt) _view.Data = New List(Of IAssignSailingPart.ISummary), Nothing, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled, uiSyncContext)
    dataTask.Start()
  End If
End Sub
```

So to start the task we call a function that queries the database for our results. On success we send this to the view, on cancellation we send an empty dataset to the view, and on failure we tell the user to try refreshing.

This all *seemed* to work okay. The users were happy with the responsiveness, etc. We've had a few issues lately though when the database server was experiencing some unrelated problems. When the fetch fails on a compiled version of the application (as opposed to within the IDE), it kills the application with an untrapped aggregate exception shortly after the actual failure has taken place. I've done some research on this and understand (or think I do) that the exception is thrown on a different thread at the point the task is garbage collected.

My question is how should I adapt the code to handle this properly? This is for a windows forms application using .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing has to do with not observing the exception in the faulted task (`dt` in this case). Each `Task` object carries a flag indicating whether its exception - if any -, was observed/accessed. When the `Task` object eventually gets finalized and that flag indicates the exception was not treated, the app will be brought down by .NET 4.0. That is a behavior which has been changed in .NET 4.5, by the way. Stephen Toub explains it in detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx).

The correct way to handle this is to look at `dt.Exception` before accessing ever trying to access `dt.Result`. When you access the `dt.Exception` property (in order to decide what to do next, or just to log the exception), that will cause the `Task` exception to be marked as observed, and the app will no longer crash upon the finalization of the `Task` instance. Directly accessing `dt.Result` on the other hand just propagates (rethrows) the exception if the `Task` is faulted.

I would also do a single `ContinueWith()` call, and check for `Task` state there (pardon my VB, I'm a C# dev):

```
 Protected Overrides Sub FetchSummary()
  If DBKey.PresentAndSet(DataKey) Then
    _view.BeginDataFetch()
    ' Cancel any active refresh
    If TaskCancelTokenSource IsNot Nothing Then TaskCancelTokenSource.Cancel()
    TaskCancelTokenSource = New CancellationTokenSource
    Dim ctok = TaskCancelTokenSource.Token
    Dim dataTask = New Task(Of IEnumerable(Of IAssignSailingPart.ISummary))(Function() FetchsummaryData(Context, DataKey), ctok)
    Dim uiSyncContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext
    dataTask.ContinueWith(Sub(dt) 
       If dt.IsFaulted Then
           _view.FailDataFetch("There was an error fetching the data, try refreshing")
           Exit Sub
       End If
       If dt.IsCancelled Then
           _view.Data = New List(Of IAssignSailingPart.ISummary)
           Exit Sub
       End If

       _view.Data = dt.Result
    End Sub, ctok, uiSyncContext)
    dataTask.Start()
  End If
End Sub
```

The reason being that when you flag a `Task` with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion`, that continuation `Task` will be marked as `Cancelled` in case `dataTask` does not run to completion, only compounding the problem.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. Normally I'm accessing the aggregate exception, which explains why we only see this on this one screen. I'd assumed that accessing the exception would fix the problem here, but I was concerned there might be something fundamentally wrong with the approach I was taking.